# Getting kendo auto complete on an element that was not already in DOM

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to get a kendo auto complete on a text box that was just appended to the Dom on 
a button click. Class of the text box is "items", and in document ready I initialized auto complete as

```
$(".items").kendoAutoComplete({})
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work!

Lets have the following HTML

```
<a id="button" class="k-button" href="#">Add</a>
<div id="here"></div>
```

And this is the Javascript

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("<div class='items'></div>").appendTo($("#here"));
    $(".items").kendoAutoComplete({});
})
```

The only problem that I foresee is that using a class for selecting where to add the `kendoAutoComplete` then you can add only one (otherwise you end up having nested autocompletes).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this.

```
$("#ButtonSelector").on('click', function() {
    $("<input class='items' />").appendTo($("#Selector"));

    $(".items", this.element).each(function () {
        $(this).kendoAutoComplete({});
    });
});
```